# Unable to access JSON files via URL in Classic ASP

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working with a classic ASP site. Currently, to run some tests using `DataTables.js` I have set a basic `json` file containing the following code:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica",
      "Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "9th Oct 09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton",
      "Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "12th Jan 09",
      "$86,000"
    ],
    [
      "Bradley",
      "Greer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "13th Oct 12",
      "$132,000"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden",
      "Wagner",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "7th Jun 11",
      "$206,850"
    ],
    [
      "Brielle",
      "Williamson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "New York",
      "2nd Dec 12",
      "$372,000"
    ],
    [
      "Bruno",
      "Nash",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "3rd May 11",
      "$163,500"
    ],
    [
      "Caesar",
      "Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "12th Dec 11",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Cara",
      "Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "6th Dec 11",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric",
      "Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "29th Mar 12",
      "$433,060"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The table is giving me the classic AJAX error warning that happens when the file is not found. Upon further inspection I have found that if I try to access the JSON file inside the url It shows as a 404, I know the file is there, because if I post a file inside that same folder as `test.asp` with something like:

```
<%
  Response.Write("Test test")
%>
```

and navigate to the same path exchanging `example.json` to `test.asp` I get the correct `"Test test"` showing in the browser.

Are there any special configurations required for the json to show? If I run this locally using the IIS Manager in my machine and go to the file it will show, but it will not show inside the application living in the sever. I am confused as to why this issue appears only in the server. A missing configuration maybe?

Comment: Hey just checking in, did this end up fixing it? Can you mark the answer if so? If not I've got a mostly free weekend, I should be able to tinker around with this if you're still stuck.

Comment: It was something similar to what you mentioned. Your answered helped me find it. Sorry for the late reply and thank you bud!

Comment: No problem, glad that worked. :)

Comment: hey buddy, do you have an example of the full page? I'm doing something similar, I have an asp page which converts a SQL query into a Json array but having trouble reading this into my datatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm missing a little bit of data here so I'm going to make some assumptions.

If you are using IIS with request filtering installed (it usually is) it sounds like the file extension may not be allowed to be served by IIS.

To resolve open the IIS Manager > select your site > Request Filtering > File Name Extension (tab), and make sure .json exists and "Allowed" = True.